# How do I add image elements to a div in javascript without using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am trying to add an image to the html page with just javascript and I have to do it without using innerHTML. I can't seem to get the images to appear at all.

javascript

```
var galleryPhotos = ["gallery/galleryphoto0.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto1.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto2.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto3.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto4.jpg"];

function newImage(){

var ele0 = document.createElement("img");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
ele0.scr = galleryPhotos[0];
image.appendChild(ele0);

var ele1 = document.createElement("img");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
ele1.scr = galleryPhotos[1];
image.appendChild(ele1);

var ele2 = document.createElement("img");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
ele2.scr = galleryPhotos[2];
image.appendChild(ele2);

var ele3 = document.createElement("img");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
ele3.scr = galleryPhotos[3];
image.appendChild(ele3);

var ele4 = document.createElement("img");
var image = document.getElementById("image");
ele4.scr = galleryPhotos[4];
image.appendChild(ele4);

}
```

What I am trying to put it into in html

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

Using chromes debugging tool doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Are you calling the `newImage()` function from anywhere?

Comment: Voting to close as this is just a simple typo: `src` not `scr`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: `scr` should be `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var galleryPhotos = ["gallery/galleryphoto0.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto1.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto2.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto3.jpg", "gallery/galleryphoto4.jpg"];

function newImage(){

     var image = document.getElementById("image");
     var i = 0;
     while(galleryPhotos[i]){
         el = document.createElement("img");
         el.src = galleryPhotos[i];
         image.appendChild(el);
         i++;
     }

}
```